# Cypress - How to click on cookies "Accept cookies" pop up

Tags: cypress

I am not able to click or even detect any element inside of Pop-up cookies on badoo.com
[image]

I am using all kind of commands like get , contains, etc. nothing works and it tells me that I didnt find element :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an `iframe` blocking your test code.

First verify this is so by right-clicking on the button, choose "Inspect element" then scroll up in the Elements panel until you find an `<iframe>` and find out it's `id=...` attribute.

To handle the iframe, the simplest way is with the [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) plugin.

**Note** the instructions given on this plugin have not been updated for Cypress version 10.

After installing, add `require('cypress-iframe');` at the top of the spec.

In the test use the following, but substitute the id you found above for `#my-iframe`

```js
cy.iframe('#my-frame')
  .find('button[title="Accept Cookies"]')
  .click()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works exactly as you described. I was thininking about that iframe, so i am little bit suprised its not already implemented in basic cypress

Comment: You're welcome. I think native iframe is on the roadmap for Cypress.

Comment: so it didnt took a long and i find another issue :D I would like to just message you with some chat instead of spaming new questions, but anyway, after my test manage to login, then my test crush, in RUN command , it just stuck in process, in OPEN command, it will reload whole page and shows files of test to run again ... maybe its some security of web against cypress?

Answer (score 0):

After another research, its enough to find ID of iframe and then put after it `.its('0.contentDocument.body')` and then its possible to find any element inside of inframe

```
cy.get('#sp_message_iframe_658470').its('0.contentDocument.body').find('button[title="Accept cookies"]').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you accept the cookies.

```
    cy.contains('Accept', { timeout: 20000 }).click({force:true})
    Cypress.on("window:before:load", () => {
        cy.state("jQuery", Cypress.$);
    });
```